# Convert ethereum tokens to inr

Tags: wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, myetherwallet

I have created an account in metamask and have got some ether tokens. Now I would like to convert them into INR so that I get hard cash.
Please let me know the procedure to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an account in an exchange that converts ether to INR.
Or you can use a peer to peer networking application like localethereum and find a buyer for your ether tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Metamask or for instance no wallet service converts ethers to fiat (including INR). What you need in an exchange.

There are number of exchanges like Koinex, Zebpay supporting INR/ETH pair.

- Just regiester yourself with one of the exchanges that provide
  ETH/INR pair.
- Get your KYC done.
- Transfer (deposit) ethers from metamask account to exchange address.
- You can then sell your ETH and receive INR in your bank account
  directly

.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just one more question! Do you know how much tax I'll have to pay for converting ether to Inr!